# WPF ToolTip disappears on mouse down

Tags: wpf, mouse, tooltip

I've got tooltip on an element that I want to stay open even when the user clicks or holds the mouse button down while over my element.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a StaysOpen tooltip property, but according to [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599551) you are better off using a Popup control (just make it look like a tool tip).

Here is a quote from the book:

> Has no effect in practice. The
>   intended purpose of this property is
>   to allow you to create a tooltip that
>   remains open until the user clicks
>   somewhere else. However, the
>   ToolTipService.ShowDuration property
>   overrides the StaysOpen property. As a
>   result, tooltips always disappear
>   after a configurable amount of time
>   (usually about 5 seconds) or when the
>   user moves the mouse away. If you want
>   to create a tooltip-like window that
>   stays open indefinitely, the easiest
>   approach is to use the Popup control.

Comment: I was afraid I was going to have to mess with the popup control. Thanks for the answer

Comment: So is the answer yes or no? This is a very annoying behavior of the Tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use Popup. Look to the code sample.

```
<!--Your ToolTip-->
<Popup x:Name="InfoPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=yourElement}" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" PopupAnimation="Fade">
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFFFF" >
        <Label Content="Your text here" />
    </Border>
</Popup>

<!--Your element. Border, Button etc..-->
<Border x:Name="yourElement" Background="#FFFFFF" MinWidth="20" Height="20">
    <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="InfoPopup">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True"></DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>

        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseUp">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="InfoPopup">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False"></DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```